# BigIP GTM persistence and time to live (TTL)

Tags: persistence, ttl, f5

How does BigIP GTM implement persistence?  Does it record the client IP address?  Since it is based on name resolution it doesn't seem like it could be based on cookies.

In order to achieve HA, it seems like the Time To Live (TTL) should be set to a relatively small value, like 30 seconds.  Yet the default is 3600 and I spent a couple of hours searching the BigIP site and could not find a recommendation to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

GTM persistence is based on source IP of the request, but that source is typically a local DNS server unless it is deployed AS the local DNS server for particular environments.

For HA, it really depends on your business SLAs. A very low TTL results in far more dns requests, impacting your infrastructure as well as client performance for clients use an LDNS server that is quite far (200ms +) from the answering GTMs. When I was a customer, I had mission critical applications set to a 30s TTL, but most of them we set to 5 minutes or longer.